# Symfony2 enable profiler but cannot reach it

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a Symfony2 project, I am trying to enable the profiler so i can do further debugging. I expect to see X-debug-token-link under Response Headers but i dont see it and i cant see the toolbar at the bottom of my page.

In my routing_dev.yml it seems that these options are enabled:

```
framework:
    router: { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: true }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

Yet I cannot reach the profiler. Is there anything I am missing...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure your `app_dev.php` or other entry point enables the debugging:

```
Debug::enable();
```

Also make sure your `routing_dev.yml` contains the profiler routes:

```
_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you run your application in `dev` or `test` environment. Even though the cookbook states that [`collect`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#collect) is enabled by default, I had to set it explicitly to activate the profiler. At least in version 2.7. Here's the configuration I use:

```
# app/config/dev/config.yml
framework:
    # activate profiler in framework
    profiler:
        collect: true

# configure profiler
web_profiler:
    # display the web debug toolbar at the bottom of pages with a summary of profiler info
    toolbar: true

    # gives you the opportunity to look at the collected data before following the redirect
    intercept_redirects: false

    # Exclude AJAX requests in the web debug toolbar for specified paths
    excluded_ajax_paths: ^/bundles|^/_wdt
```

Further reading:

- [FrameworkBundle Configuration ("framework") `profiler`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#profiler)
- [WebProfilerBundle Configuration ("web_profiler")](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/web_profiler.html)